# Sybase polling performance impact

Tags: java, database, performance, sybase, sap-ase

We have a Sybase ASE simple table, with one column, like below

```
Table Name: Items
+------------+
|  itemId    | 
+------------+
| ABCDEFGH1  |
| ABCDEFGH2  |
+------------+
itemId is the primary key.
```

A producer would populate this table with data at an undeterministic rate.

We have a consumer (Java process) which polls this table constantly (using JDBC), by doing

```
SELECT TOP 5000 itemId FROM Items ORDER BY itemId desc
```

And these itemIds will be deleted by the consumer a bit later after successful processing (say every 200ms). 
**We can assume that the consumer is ALWAYS faster than producer**, which means the number of records in the table would rarely go above 5000.

We poll constantly because we'd like updates to be sent to the consumer as soon as possible, to simulate "push" behavior.

My questions:

1. What's the performance impact on this approach.
2. Why these performance impact, can they be explained in theory and verified in practice (if anyone can share ideas on how to make an environment to verify this and evaluate the results)

Comment: I guess it depends on how often you are polling, and therefore how often you need to poll for the consumer to stay ahead of the producer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what does Sybase do? would it put anything in memory cache because of this constant polling on a small table using "order by"? Or every time I am hitting the hard drive but with very little CPU and memory consumption? Any ideas on setting up a good environment to test this? Or this is something pretty much can be neglected because of resources used on this would be tiny?

Comment: I don't quite understand the fixed polling for 5000 rows? If the producer is inserting rows until a certain point then stopping, at which point you then pick them up before it deletes them, surely the producer setting a semaphore/status in a separate table would be better to allow some interaction between them rather than assuming 5k rows is always ok? This gives you the ability to do an 'if exists (select 1 from <status_table> ...do some action' type SQL which would poll for anything in that table and be massively less workload to the database rather than reading 5k keys

Answer (score 1):

(assuming there's only one consumer here, so no coordination is required between consumers)

If itemId is a primary key (table created with the "primary key" constraint on the itemId column), then Sybase implicitly created a unique clustered index on the column.

So your "top 5000" command should use the clustered index to scan the table.  I assume that once the consumer gets a batch of rows, it stops polling/scanning until it's done processing and has deleted the processed itemId's.

So you're really talking about running the "SELECT TOP 5000 itemId FROM Items" query on a frequent basis (polling) when the table is empty, right?

Assuming this is the case (running select on an empty table), it will run very quickly, but if you run it continuously, it will potentially use up all your Sybase CPU with thousands of empty polls per second.  Maybe you're talking about polling once a second?  That should be fine.

More thoughts:

If you start talking about crazy high insert rates with ascending key values to a clustered index, then you might get into things like optimizing page splits for the clustered index.  See "Effects of Ascending Inserts" at:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/21022a83c8474f31b3ac1b5ec4075dba/16.0.3.4/en-US/a9f00f15bc2b1014af52b7854bca5497.html

I'm guessing this is not where you're at.

Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben. I am curious to know why "it will potentially use up all your Sybase CPU with thousands of empty polls per second.". 
I would assume the "deadloop" empty table query would either
1. use some IO, which means CPU wouldn't be too busy because IO is much slower
2. not much IO but in that case, I assume Sybase has cached the knowledge of the table being empty (otherwise how would it know)? But if it is cached somehow, I imagine it would use very small number of CPU cycles?

Comment: How many times will you call the poll per second?  If you have a select statement that only takes 1 millisecond of CPU time, but you call it a 1000 times/second, that's 100% of a CPU.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the call is synchronous, which means the second call wouldn't be started before the first call is completed. The scale we are talking is more like that IO is taking 1 second to complete while CPU only need 1 nanosecond for each query.